# Remove * from label in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQUery in my application .

Inthat i am having a

```
    <label id="label1">Firstname<span class="req"><em> * </em></span></label>

   $("#label"+div_id+"").clone();
  clone.remove('span');
  alert(clone.text());//displaying FirstName*
```

But i need only Firstname

How to do so in JQUery..Or else is there any method to keep * near Firstname in the label and to retrieve only Firstname  instead of span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
var clone = $("#label1").clone();                                                       
$("span",clone).remove();
alert(clone.text());
```

or

```
alert(  $("#label1").clone().html().replace(/<span.*/,'')  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span', clone).remove ()
```

Here, `clone` is the so-called 'context' of the jQuery call, meaning, that jQuery searches spans only inside `clone`.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($("#label1").text().substring(0,($("#label1").text()).length-3));
```